# Insert spaces into a string

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I have a string and I want to insert spaces between the digits.

Example:

Input String: `123456`

Output String: `1 2 3 4 5 6`

Comment: You should include details on how you want to "split" and what output you want. And to show that you did think about it before asking, show something that you tried.

Comment: For example, for the output of the split do you want a new string? Or did you want a `std::vector< std::string >`?

Answer (score 2):

You could just call the string as an array

```
std::string str = "123456";
std::string new_string = ""; 
int string_length = 6;
for(int i=0; i<string_length; i++){
    new_string += str[i];
    if(i != string_length-1) { new_string += " "; }
}
```

There are more efficient ways to do it, but this illustrates the behavior in an easily understandable way, with little steps at a time.

Comment: I think you meant to add `" "` instead of `""`;

Answer (score 1):

With range-v3 you could do:

```
namespace rv = ranges::views;  
auto res = s | rv::intersperse(' ') | ranges::to<std::string>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/gh4gMd).

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to implement your own custom split function.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool isDigit(char c){
    return (c>='0' && c<='9');
}

std::string splitOnDigits(std::string s){

    std::string out = "";

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){

        if(isDigit(s[i-1]) || (!isdigit(s[i-1]) && isDigit(s[i]))){
            out += " ";
        }

        out += s[i];
    }
    return out;
}
int main()
{
    std::string s = "123456";

    std::cout<<splitOnDigits(s)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: The poster only wants single spaces, not double.

Comment: look for [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit). You don't need to provide one.

Comment: @ Ken Y-N, updated! Thanks for pointing out the error. I think you can remove the downvote now